# Orthogonal decomposition in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

> **Corollary 2.76 (Orthogonal decomposition).** Let H be a Hilbert space,
>   and let $Y \subset H$ be a closed subspace. Then $Y^\bot $ is a closed subspace with
>   $$H = Y \oplus Y^\bot$$,
>   meaning that every element $h \in H$ can be written in the form
>   $$h = y + z$$
>   with $y \in Y$ and $z \in Y^\bot$ and $y$ and $z$ are unique with these properties

The uniqueness part is easily shown. But for the existance part it's said that we want to use the unique approximation within a closed convex set (i.e $\forall w\in V \exists ! v_o\in K \text{ s.t. } \|w-v_0\|=\inf_{k\in K}\|k-v_0\|$). The argumentation goes as follows:

> Fix $h \in H$, and
>   apply Theorem 2.73 with $K = Y$ to find a point $y \in Y$ that is closest to $h$.
>   Let $z := h − y$, so that for any $v \in Y$ and any scalar $t$ we have (noting that the first inequality holds because $(tv+y)\in Y$ and is strict for all $t\ne0$ by the lemma and the second equality holds for the properties of the inner product) 
>   $$\|z\|^2\le\|h-(tv+y)\|^2=\|z-tv\|=\|z\|^2-2\Re(t\langle v,z\rangle)+|t|^2\|v\|^2$$

(And now the problematic part)

> **However**, this shows that
>   $$\Re(t\langle v,z\rangle)=0$$
>   for all scalars $t$ and $v \in Y$ , and so
>   $$\langle v,z\rangle=0$$

How should I interpret that **"However"**? Where should I use the fact that this particular $y$ is the **unique** closest in $Y$?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: In the inequality, it should be $t^2 \|v\|^2$.

Comment: thanks, I have corrected the question (the module must stay because $t$ is not necessarily real)

Comment: The best approximation property is used in the inequality. It reads:

Since $y \in Y$ is the best approximation of $b$, for any $t \in \mathbb{F}$, any $v \in Y$, we have $y + tv \in Y$ satisfies $\|h - y\|^2 \leq \|h - (y + tv)\|^2$.

Comment: yes, that was clear (although not from how I wrote the question). What I don't know is whether I shall use the strict inequality somewhere or not.

Comment: You don't have to use the strict inequality. You're inequailty reads as $ \forall t \in \mathbb{C}, \forall v \in Y : \ 2 \Re (t \langle v, z \rangle ) \leq |t|^2 \| v \|^2 $. This already implies the result. To be more precise, you might take $ t = s \langle v, z \rangle $ for $ s \in \mathbb{R} $ and reconsider your inequality, which leads you to the precise result... Anyhow, I'm pretty sure, Einsiedler will not ask for such details at the exam :)

Comment: haha! Thanks m.g :) enjoy!

Comment: May I know, from which book/notes the definitions in the OP are taken from? I am in particular looking for the orthogonal decomposition part!

Comment: Sure: Functional Analysis, Spectral Theory, and Applications by M. Einsiedler and T. Ward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "however" has no reversal meaning to me. The details goes as follows:

For any $t \neq 0$, any $v \in Y \setminus \{0\}$, $\|z\|^2 \leq \|z\|^2 - 2t\Re(v,z) + |t|^2\|v\|^2$ and therefore

$$2\Re(t(v,z)) \leq |t|^2\|v\|^2$$

In particular take $t = \frac{\bar{(v,z)}}{\|v\|^2}$. We obtain

$$2\frac{|(v,z)|^2}{\|v\|^2} = 2\Re(\frac{|(v,z)|^2}{\|v\|^2}) \leq \frac{|(v,z)|^2}{\|v\|^4}\|v\|^2 = \frac{|(v,z)|^2}{\|v\|^2}$$

which implies $|(v,z)|^2 = 0$ and finally $(v,z) = 0$.

Comment: thank you SRX... Such a misleading choice of words...